# Derived categories of coherent sheaves and degenerations of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, derived-categories

By the work of Burban-Drozd (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1076621984), we know what happens to the derived category of coherent sheaves when an elliptic curve degenerates into a nodal curve or a cycle of projective lines, namely let $C$ be such a curve with $n$ double points, then $D^b\mathit{Coh}(C)$ is generated by $\mathcal{O}_{p_1},\dots,\mathcal{O}_{p_n},\mathcal{O}_C$, where $p_1,\dots,p_n\in C$ are smooth points.

Is there any generalization of their result to degenerations of higher dimensional abelian varieties?